# How to get the highest value from list of Device Names

Tags: windows, powershell

Generating a list of windows workstation computer names by reading the active directory and I need to find the highest number so that I can then assign a new device with the next available number - I am not having any success in doing this - how to do it? And as you can see from the list of names, I also have missing numbers in the sequence that ideally, I would like to fill in with new devices also...

The code I am using to get the list from AD is below.

```
((Get-ADComputer -Filter {operatingsystem -notlike "*server*" -and Name -like $NamingConvention -and enabled -eq "true"} -Credential $credential -server $ADServerIP).Name)
```

List of device names

> PC01
> PC28
> PC29
> PC30
> PC31
> PC32
> PC33
> PC34
> PC35
> PC36
> PC37
> PC38
> PC40
> PC41
> PC42
> PC43
> PC44
> PC45
> PC46
> PC47
> PC27
> PC48
> PC26
> PC24
> PC179
> PC18
> PC180
> PC181
> PC182
> PC183
> PC184
> PC185
> PC186
> PC187
> PC188
> PC189
> PC19
> PC190
> PC191
> PC192
> PC21
> PC22
> PC23
> PC25
> PC178
> PC49
> PC51
> PC77
> PC78
> PC79
> PC80
> PC81
> PC83
> PC84
> PC85
> PC87
> PC88
> PC89
> PC90
> PC91
> PC92
> PC93
> PC94
> PC95
> PC96
> PC97
> PC76
> PC50
> PC75
> PC72
> PC52
> PC53
> PC54
> PC55
> PC56
> PC57
> PC59
> PC60
> PC61
> PC62
> PC63
> PC64
> PC65
> PC66
> PC67
> PC68
> PC69
> PC70
> PC71
> PC73
> PC98
> PC177
> PC175
> PC115
> PC116
> PC117
> PC118
> PC119
> PC12
> PC120
> PC121
> PC122
> PC123
> PC124
> PC125
> PC126
> PC127
> PC128
> PC129
> PC13
> PC130
> PC131
> PC114
> PC132
> PC113
> PC111
> PC02
> PC03
> PC04
> PC06
> PC08
> PC09
> PC10
> PC100
> PC101
> PC102
> PC103
> PC104
> PC105
> PC106
> PC107
> PC108
> PC109
> PC11
> PC110
> PC112
> PC176
> PC133
> PC135
> PC158
> PC159
> PC16
> PC160
> PC161
> PC162
> PC163
> PC164
> PC165
> PC166
> PC167
> PC168
> PC169
> PC17
> PC170
> PC171
> PC172
> PC173
> PC174
> PC157
> PC134
> PC156
> PC154
> PC136
> PC137
> PC138
> PC139
> PC14
> PC140
> PC141
> PC142
> PC143
> PC144
> PC145
> PC146
> PC147
> PC148
> PC149
> PC150
> PC151
> PC152
> PC153
> PC155
> PC99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that will give you the highest number `($dataMax)`, the missing numbers `($dataMissing)`, and the next number to use `($dataNext)`. The next number to use will be either the 1st missing number, or if there are no missing numbers then it will be the highest number + 1

```
# load the computers list
$data = ((Get-ADComputer -Filter {operatingsystem -notlike "*server*" -and Name -like $NamingConvention -and enabled -eq "true"} -Credential $credential -server $ADServerIP).Name)

# create an array by splitting the data text using the "space" character as a delimiter
$data = $data.Split(" ")

# remove all the alpha characters ("PC"), leaving only the number values so it can be sorted easier
$dataCleaned = $data -replace "[^0-9]" , '' | sort { [int]$_ }

# after sorting the data, [-1] represents the last element in the array which will be the highest number
[int]$dataMax = $dataCleaned[-1]

# create a number range that represents all the numbers from 1 to the highest number
$range = 1..$dataMax | foreach-object { '{0:d2}' -f $_ }

# compare the created range against the numbers actually in the computer array to find the missing numbers
$dataMissing = @(compare $range $dataCleaned -PassThru)

# if there's a missing value, [0] represents the first element in the array of missing numbers
if ($dataMissing)
{
    $dataNext = $dataMissing[0]
}

# if there's no missing values, the next value is the max value + 1
else
{
    $dataMissing = "none"
    $dataNext = $dataMax + 1
}

Write-Host "The highest number is:"('{0:d2}' -f $dataMax)
Write-Host "The missing numbers are: $dataMissing"
Write-Host "The next number to use is:" ('{0:d2}' -f $dataNext)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. One final question - how to pad the single-digit numbers with a 0 - i.e. 01, 02 etc.

Comment: Updated answer to use string-formatting with a leading zero '`{0:d2}' -f` for all 3 variables

Comment: in this list below the next number to use keeps coming up with 3 for some reason that I cannot work out...

VOY-LAPTOP01 thought to VOY-LAPTOP47.  number 35 is missing, however, number 3 is present in regards to VOY-LAPTOP03.  This script reports the next number to use is 3

Comment: I've updated the answer (line 17), as `$dataMissing` when only containing 1 missing number (35), the variable is a string, so `$dataMissing[0]` corresponds to the 1st character in the string (3). `$dataMissing[1]` would be the 2nd character (5). The update sets the variable to an array type even when there's only 1 element

Answer (score 1):

Sort the pc names on their numeric values and select the last one:

```
$lastPC = (Get-ADComputer -Filter {operatingsystem -notlike "*server*" -and Name -like $NamingConvention -and enabled -eq "true"} -Credential $credential -server $ADServerIP).Name  | 
           Sort-Object { [int]($_ -replace '\D+')} | Select-Object -Last 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list is exactly as it appears to be, then this appears to be one way to do it:

```
$List = 'PC01 PC28 PC29 PC30 PC31 PC32 PC33 PC34 PC35 PC36 PC37 PC38 PC40 PC41 PC42 PC43 PC44 PC45 PC46 PC47 PC27 PC48 PC26 PC24 PC179 PC18 PC180 PC181 PC182 PC183 PC184 PC185 PC186 PC187 PC188 PC189 PC19 PC190 PC191 PC192 PC21 PC22 PC23 PC25 PC178 PC49 PC51 PC77 PC78 PC79 PC80 PC81 PC83 PC84 PC85 PC87 PC88 PC89 PC90 PC91 PC92 PC93 PC94 PC95 PC96 PC97 PC76 PC50 PC75 PC72 PC52 PC53 PC54 PC55 PC56 PC57 PC59 PC60 PC61 PC62 PC63 PC64 PC65 PC66 PC67 PC68 PC69 PC70 PC71 PC73 PC98 PC177 PC175 PC115 PC116 PC117 PC118 PC119 PC12 PC120 PC121 PC122 PC123 PC124 PC125 PC126 PC127 PC128 PC129 PC13 PC130 PC131 PC114 PC132 PC113 PC111 PC02 PC03 PC04 PC06 PC08 PC09 PC10 PC100 PC101 PC102 PC103 PC104 PC105 PC106 PC107 PC108 PC109 PC11 PC110 PC112 PC176 PC133 PC135 PC158 PC159 PC16 PC160 PC161 PC162 PC163 PC164 PC165 PC166 PC167 PC168 PC169 PC17 PC170 PC171 PC172 PC173 PC174 PC157 PC134 PC156 PC154 PC136 PC137 PC138 PC139 PC14 PC140 PC141 PC142 PC143 PC144 PC145 PC146 PC147 PC148 PC149 PC150 PC151 PC152 PC153 PC155 PC99'
$NextNumber = ($List -split "\s" | ForEach-Object { if ($_ -match 'PC(?<Number>\d+)') { $Matches.Number } }  | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum + 1
$NextNumber
"PC$NextNumber"
```