# Powershell to list free domain computers

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm using PowerShell to get a lit of all our domain computers, and then look for ones that are skipped, so we can easily get free computer names within this name range.

For example:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like "PC016*"} | Sort-Object | select Name
```

This gets me all our PCs starting with "PC016", and it works. From here I want to list all the skipped names.

For example, if I have this output:

```
PC016225
PC016226
PC016228
PC016229
```

I want Powershell to list the skipped item (`PC016227`).

How can I do this?

Comment: Check the answers in this similar thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72068893/how-to-get-the-highest-value-from-list-of-device-names/72069243

Comment: This seems weird to me. Either the names are **meaningful**, where the number should tell you something related to at least, say, the age of the computer and back-filling old names breaks that meaning, or they are **not meaningful** such that skipped names _don't matter_ and you can keep incrementing the counter forever. Both choices have merit; this idea of trying filling in every number is like chasing a ghost.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn not necessarily true. Imagine the first 3 digits carry meaning and you have some legacy inventory system that only accepts asset descriptions in the form `XYDDDDDD` - constraining you to only pick 3-digit suffixes, you may have to do some "defragmentation" like this. Real life IT is messier than you think :)

Comment: Yes, the numbers have a meaning. The 16 determines the subnet, so the maximum number would be PC016255, since theres only 255 addresses available (We still use manually assigned ip addresses

Answer (score 1):

Remove the prefix from the names so you're left with the numerical suffix (eg. `225`), then *sort* the resulting values to easily locate the lowest and highest values, and then simply output any number in between that *isn't* in the original list:

```
# Define computer name prefix
$prefix = "PC016"

# Create regex pattern for the prefix + a pattern to match only computer names ending with numbers
$prefixPattern = "^$([regex]::Escape($prefix))"
$namePattern   = "${prefixPattern}\d+$"

# Query the directory for computer objects with the given naming prefix,
# filter the result so we only store computers with a numerical suffix
$computerNames = Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like '${prefix}*'" |Where-Object Name -match $namePattern |ForEach-Object Name

# Extract the numerical suffix and convert to a numeric type
$values = @($computerNames -replace $prefixPattern) -as [int[]]

# Sort the values
$values = $values |Sort-Object 

# Now generate the range of values from the smallest to the biggest, 
# filter out any values that are already found in the existing list
$skipped = $values[0]..$values[-1] |Where-Object { $_ -notin $values }

# ... and finally attach the prefix again and output the new possible names
$skipped |ForEach-Object { -join $prefix,$_ }
```